# Tool for creating a video from an audio file, video file and slides?

Tags: video, audio, editing, slideshow

I'd like to create a video file from 3 sources mixed: audio file, video file and slides. Could you recommend me a tool? I must say I have no experience in video edition.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

On linux, the best tool is [dvd-slideshow](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Main_Page).  You *could* get this to run under windows, but it would take a bit of work.

It takes a text file of instructions as input, but allows for the easy addition of images, title slides, transition effects and multiple audio tracks.  The text file format is basic.  1 command per line, `#` lines are  comments.

There is a related too called [dir2slideshow](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Dir2slideshow_0.8.0).  If you want to make a quick & dirty dvd of all the images in a directory, you could do this:

```
dir2slideshow -n "Thanksgiving 2009" <Your images directory>
```

dvd-slideshow gives you full control over every image or effect individually.  For example:

```
dvd-slideshow [-n <slideshow name>] [-o <output directory>] [-b <background jpeg>] [-a <audiofile1> -a <audiofile2> -a <audiofileN>] [-p] [-L] [-H] [-mp2] [-r] [-smp] -f <input text file>
```

The -f specifies the commands that provide all the instructions to the program.

The finished product are all the files you need to provide to a standard burner to make a dvd.  There are several [simple examples](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Simple_Example) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

1.[AviDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) (windows, linux and mac)

- Pro: Powerful, Easy to use, Well documented tutorials
- Con:  As with any other video editing program, it can be confusing.

2.[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) (windows only)

- Pro: Great piece of software for the power user who is really familiar with video editing
- Con: Can be quite confusing for the average user.

3.[Pincale Video Spin](http://videospin.com/redesign/default.asp) (windows only)

- Pro: Very simple interface with some cool features
- Con: Lack of advanced tools gives this program a childish feel.

Source: [gizmo's freeware](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-video-editor.htm)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at Windows Movie Maker, you can add audio to video files or create slideshows from images, it's pretty easy to use and novice-friendly.

caveat: it can only create WMV videos (which can be converted, of course),

unfortunately, Microsoft has removed many interesting features from the new Windows Live Movie Maker (e.g. creating slideshows from images), but all is not lost: you can download the **fully featured, portable Windows Movie Maker 2.1** [here](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk). works with XP, Vista and Windows 7.

and here is a tutorial: **[Adding Music and Sounds in Windows Movie Maker](http://presentationsoft.about.com/od/moviemaker/ss/audio.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `ffmpeg`.

e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.
```

http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC14